# mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Failed parsing EOF packet

Tags: mysql, django

I run into such problems when I running my Django project(a week ago, the project work properly, today find this problem):
My Django version is 1.10.2 with python version 3.5.2, MySQL version is 5.5 on ubuntu 14.0.

```
/Users/deja/Virtualenv/python3.5/bin/python3.5 /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 60850 --file /Users/mozat/project/crawler_management_system/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:6380
pydev debugger: process 81527 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 145.1504)
pydev debugger: process 81528 is connecting

Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 13 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
January 03, 2017 - 07:55:47
Django version 1.10.2, using settings 'crawler_management_system.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:6380/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/deja/Virtualenv/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 226, in recv_plain
    chunk = self.sock.recv(4 - packet_len)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mozat/project/crawler_management_system/crawler_management_system/mysql_utility.py", line 32, in open_db
    raise err
  File "/Users/mozat/project/crawler_management_system/crawler_management_system/mysql_utility.py", line 28, in open_db
    yield cursor
  File "/Users/mozat/project/crawler_management_system/crawler_management_system/views.py", line 40, in select_batch_records
    cursor.execute(sql.format(table=self.table,times=times))
  File "/Users/deja/Virtualenv/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 515, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/Users/deja/Virtualenv/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 488, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/Users/deja/Virtualenv/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 267, in _send_cmd
    return self._socket.recv()
  File "/Users/deja/Virtualenv/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 255, in recv_plain
    errno=2055, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at '127.0.0.1:10189', system error: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/deja/Virtualenv/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 710, in reset_session
    self.cmd_reset_connection()
  File "/Users/deja/Virtualenv/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 1046, in cmd_reset_connection
    raise errors.NotSupportedError("MySQL version 5.7.2 and "
mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: MySQL version 5.7.2 and earlier does not support COM_RESET_CONNECTION.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/deja/Virtualenv/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/protocol.py", line 267, in parse_eof
    unpacked = struct_unpack('<xxxBBHH', packet)
struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 9

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/deja/Virtualenv/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/deja/Virtualenv/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/Users/deja/Virtualenv/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/deja/Virtualenv/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/mozat/project/crawler_management_system/crawler_management_system/views.py", line 99, in mainpage
    result = batch_record_repo.select_batch_records(times)
  File "/Users/mozat/project/crawler_management_system/crawler_management_system/views.py", line 41, in select_batch_records
    return cursor.fetchall()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/Users/mozat/project/crawler_management_system/crawler_management_system/mysql_utility.py", line 40, in open_db
    connection.close()
  File "/Users/deja/Virtualenv/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/pooling.py", line 117, in close
    cnx.reset_session()
  File "/Users/deja/Virtualenv/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 713, in reset_session
    self._database, self._charset_id)
  File "/Users/deja/Virtualenv/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 661, in cmd_change_user
    self._post_connection()
  File "/Users/deja/Virtualenv/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 695, in _post_connection
    self.set_charset_collation(self._charset_id)
  File "/Users/deja/Virtualenv/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 654, in set_charset_collation
    charset_name, collation_name))
  File "/Users/deja/Virtualenv/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 869, in _execute_query
    self.cmd_query(query)
  File "/Users/deja/Virtualenv/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 488, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/Users/deja/Virtualenv/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 393, in _handle_result
    return self._handle_eof(packet)
  File "/Users/deja/Virtualenv/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 344, in _handle_eof
    eof = self._protocol.parse_eof(packet)
  File "/Users/deja/Virtualenv/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/protocol.py", line 269, in parse_eof
    raise errors.InterfaceError(err_msg)
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Failed parsing EOF packet.
[03/Jan/2017 07:56:40] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 172448
```

anyone happen to see same problem?Could you please give me some suggestion.

Comment: Did you try restarting your MySQL server?

Comment: see my answer please.

Answer (score 0):

all ,nothing wrong with mysql, and Django. It's for I use a complex SQL to access mysql:

```
            SELECT *
              FROM
                (SELECT *,
                  @batch_rank := IF(@current_batch = spider , @batch_rank + 1, 1) AS batch_rank,
                  @current_batch := spider
                FROM deja_crawler.crawl_batch_record
                where spider in (select distinct spider from deja_crawler.crawl_batch_record where spider like '%_new' or spider like '%_update')
                ORDER BY spider, create_time DESC)
              ranked
            WHERE batch_rank <= 3
```

the tables used to have not too much data, so it works, later, the table became huge, and the access time cost is almost 30s, but the connection time out is set as 20s, so it will raise time out error.